# Error "inotify_add_watch" when pushing to bitbucket

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, inotify

I started to get an error suddently when pushing any branch of a certain project to bitbucket.

When I do: `git push`, I get the following:

```
inotify_add_watch: No such file or directory
registerToSubTree : warning, failed to register /home/user/workspace/project/.git/refs/remotes/origin/dev.lock :Error watching /home/user/workspace/project/.git/refs/remotes/origin/dev.lock : No such file or directory
```

What can be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running this from the command line, or are you working within an IDE such as Eclipse?

Comment: from the command line. I do use an IDE (Aptana, which runs under Eclipse), but all the git commands are from the shell. I'm having this problem on an Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: OK - and which version of git are you using?

Comment: Can you upgrade to the current stable version, 1.8.0.1? Your version of git is over three years old. You can [get it here](http://git-scm.com/downloads) or with `apt-get`.

Comment: I can't. apt get says this is the last version for me and your link also points the version I already have for ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 3):

I've just had this error when committing from the command line (using Ubuntu 13.04 with git 1.8.1.2).

```
$:~/dev/myLogger$ git push origin master
**Everything up-to-date**
inotify_add_watch: No such file or directory
registerToSubTree : warning, 
    failed to register /home/me/dev/myLogger/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock :
    Error watching /home/me/dev/myLogger/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock : No such file or directory
```

I had Eclipse (with the Aptana Plugin for HTML development) open.

Closing Eclipse and rerunning the command and the error went away.